# VWP/ESTA eligibility after AOS during a previous admission

Tags: usa, customs-and-immigration, us-visa-waiver-program, overstaying

I am a citizen of the United Kingdom and a prior holder of a US Green Card. I successfully immigrated to the United States after being admitted under the VWP by adjusting my status within the 90 day period. As I never intended to immigrate when I entered the US, and I later married a US citizen, my application was approved. My petition (Form I-485) was received before my I-94 expired, and so I did not accrue unlawful presence.

Am I eligible to use the VWP in the future?

Answer (score 4):

> Am I eligible to use the VWP in the future?

If your ESTA application is successful, yes.

You indicate that you are no longer a US permanent resident.  If you haven't formally abandoned your permanent residence (form I-407) or been found to have abandoned it, for example by an immigration judge, then you may have to file I-407 before you'll be admitted.

Unlawful presence isn't *per se* relevant to the VWP; if you had accrued enough of it you would be inadmissible, period, even with a visa.  Ineligibility to use the VWP arises under 8 USC 1187(a)(7) from any noncompliance with the conditions of a VWP admission, regardless of whether unlawful presence is accrued:

> (7) No previous violation
>
> If the alien previously was admitted without a visa under this section, the alien must not have failed to comply with the conditions of any previous admission as such a nonimmigrant.

Some might argue that your having adjusted status is a violation of a condition of your admission, but the prohibition against adjusting status that applies to most VWP visitors is imposed by the statutory provisions concerning adjustment of status rather than those concerning the visa waiver program, and in any event it does not apply to you because you adjusted status as an immediate relative of a US citizen.

Comment: But the fact that they stayed in the US after the end of their VWP admission period is a violation of VWP, regardless of the fact that they had a pending AOS and that AOS applicants are not normally deported.

Comment: @user102008 is that the actual interpretation employed by DHS?  Is it documented anywhere?  If so, I would like to add it to the answer.  Would the ESTA system pick this up and refuse authorization?